# How to get imageview of tabBarItem in iOS 13 and above?

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

I need the imageView of tabBarItem to animate it while selecting. I was able to get the imageView before iOS 13 like this:

```
tabItem.subviews.flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }.first
```

But now the subView only contains the UIVisualEffectView as its only subview and I'm not able to get the imageView of tabBarItem.

I'm using Xcode 11.1 and iOS13.1 iPhone 11.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 13, when a tab is not selected you can access `UIVisualEffectView`'s `contentView`. Traverse the subviews of the `contentView` (`UIVisualEffectView.contentView.subviews`) and you should find `UISwappableImageView`.

When the tab is selected, you should see the `UISwappableImageView` as a child of `UITabBarItem`.

Comment: UISwappableImageView extends UIImageView so this works: ...(UIVisualEffectView).contentView.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIImageView }).first

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to directly access the image/selectedImage property of the tabBarItem as `tabBar.items![index].image` and `tabBar.items![index].selectedImage` AFAIK.

Comment: I need the object of imageView, not the image. My question is regarding the imageView not selected image or image